# How do I get the console to output my number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, let

I'm just a beginner in JavaScript and I can't solve a problem with a function. I need the code to cycle through an array of let's say the numbers `["3", "5", "7", "4", "9"]` and `console.log` only the highest number in the array. This is the code I'm working with and I had tried many variations to get the function to `console.log` the number 9 in this case. What is the proper way to insert an array here and I need to switch the `return max` to `console.log(max)`. Until now I just had an error or the console wont show anything, I need an answer at this point to get me through it.

```
function findMax(arr){
  let max = arr[0];
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] > max){
      max = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: um.... `var x = findMax([1,4,8,9]); console.log(x);`

Comment: Note that, you have an array of strings. If you have `"10"`, it will still output `"9"`

Answer (score -2):

```js
function findMax(arr){
  let max = arr[0];
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] > max){
      max = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(findMax(['1','2','3','4','5']))
console.log(findMax([1,2,3,4,5]))
```